# Is there a way to capture the failure output of lineinfile in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with `lineinfile`. I need to capture the failure.
When I use `register` the failed ones of `lineinfile` are not being capture also the success one does not have enough information like a general register values. (Eg. there is no rc code, stdout or anything)

I need to capture the hosts on which the `lineinfile` task failed.

Please let me know if there is any method to achieve the requirement.

`lineinfile:
      path: /test
      regexp: "^host"
      line: "host myhost 127.0.0.1"
      state: present
    register: result`

I am trying capture this message that is displayed in the verbose but unable to capture it with a register so that I can use the when condition and say when rc == 257 it is to be marked as failed.

`fatal: [examplehost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backrefs": false,
            "backup": true,
            "content": null,
            "create": false,
            "delimiter": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "firstmatch": false,
            "follow": false,
            "force": null,
            "group": null,
            "insertafter": null,
            "insertbefore": null,
            "line": "HOST example.something 127.0.0.1",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "path": "/test/my",
            "regexp": "^HOST",
            "remote_src": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Destination /test/my does not exist !",
    "rc": 257`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your complaint; `lineinfile:` is going to ensure that line appears in the target file, and will only use the `regexp:` bit to assist it in placing the line. If the file does not have a line that starts with `host`, then `lineinfile:` will just append the `line:` to the bottom of the file, and cheerfully report that it did so in `result.msg`: 

`changed: [host0] => {"backup": "", "changed": true, "msg": "line added"}
changed: [host1] => {"backup": "", "changed": true, "msg": "line replaced"}`

Comment: Thank you for the response. So say for example there are 100 servers where I am trying to do a change with line in file, out of which 10 fails because that does not have the file. What I would like to do is capture that 10 servers that failed in a file and mark it as FAILED, Capture the successful one and mark them as SUCCESS

Comment: I am trying capture this message that is displayed in the verbose but unable to capture it with a register so that I can use the when condition and say when rc == 257 it is to be marked as failed.